# $\sigma$-finite measure equivalences with disjoint sets

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> **Definition** Let $X$ a set. If there are sets ${\displaystyle X_{1},X_{2},\ldots \in X}$ with ${\displaystyle \mu \left(A_{n}\right)<\infty }$ for all ${\displaystyle n\in \mathbb {N} }$ that satisfy ${\displaystyle \bigcup _{n\in \mathbb {N} }X_{n}=X}$, then X calls $\sigma$-finite.

**Problem**

If $X$ is $\sigma$-finite, then there are sets sets ${\displaystyle B_{1},B_{2},\ldots \in {X}}$ with ${\displaystyle \mu \left(B_{n}\right)<\infty }$ for all ${\displaystyle n\in \mathbb {N} }$ and ${\displaystyle B_{i}\cap B_{j}=\varnothing }$ for ${\displaystyle i\neq j}$ that satisfy ${\displaystyle \bigcup _{n\in \mathbb {N} }B_{n}=X}$.

My idea is form the ${\displaystyle B_{i}}$ using ${\displaystyle X_{i}}$ but i don't know how to relate it, could you help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\displaystyle \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X_n =X$ with $m(X_n)<\infty$ for all $n$. Construct $\{B_n\}$ as follows.

$B_1=X_1$, $B_2=X_2 \backslash X_1,$ $B_3=X_3\backslash (X_1\cup X_2),...,$ $B_n=X_n\backslash \cup_{j=1}^{n-1}X_j$. Then it's easy to show that for all $n,$ we have $m(B_n)<\infty$ and $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n = X$. Moreover, the sets are mutually disjoint.